# How to inject JS to multiple frames in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

In iOS, webview is [capable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscript/3656354-initwithsource?language=objc) to inject JS to all frames (including iFrame), how can we achieve the same in android?

I can't see option to do the same thing in the [evaluateJavascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) webview function.

Otherwise, is there any way to bypass this? possibly by [intercepting request](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))?

I'm trying to inject a JS in iframe to help user autofill data in my app